# Percentage increase between two data points - bar chart / Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Please forgive me but I simply do not know how to include these arrow lines displaying percentage increase/decrease between two points on a bar chart in excel. I wish to replicate what is showing in the image with current data.

I have a printed excel bar chart, in between bars there are arrows with a speech bubble in the middle displaying the percentage difference between each bar, ie - bar one - bar two (percentage increase), bar two - bar three (percentage increase) and so on. The arrow comes up, across (with speech bubble %) and finishes pointing down, Akin to half a rectangle.

I then need a horizontal/diagonal line from bar one to last bar displaying overall percentage increase in same format.

[image]

Comment: Edit your question to include a **link** to your image and someone with sufficient reputation will insert it for you.

Comment: Have you tried using `Insert > Shape` to draw these labels on?